# Windows Server 2008 R2 RODC shows no installed updates, won't install updates, won't run DCPROMO to allow demotion

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rpc, rodc

I have a Windoer 2008 R2 RODC. It runs AD DS and DNS and that's it. The install is less than a day old.

Windows update hangs at "downloading updates" indefinitely, Server Manager errors on refresh with "The Remote Procedure Call failed. (Exception from HRESULT:0x800706BE)", the Windows System Update Rediness tool hangs on "searching for updates" and if I go into control panel and look at installed updates, it shows me that none are installed, even though there are at least 20 that I installed yesterday.

I figured, even if I can recover this server I don't trust it, so I was going to run DCPROMO and demote it, then unjoin it, format and reinstall and repromote. Unfortunately, when I run DCPROMO I get an error saying that it couldn't detect if Active Directory binaries were installed.

Everything in the event logs seems to reference RPC in one way or another. Has anyone seen this? Should I just format and reinstall? If so, is the procedure to delete an unrecoverable RODC the same as for a normal DC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ntdsutil to remove the RODC from AD and just reinstalled and promoted it again and everything was fine. It seems it was just a botched Windows install for some reason.